# C++ set function for multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, set

So I have a multidimensional array in a class declared this way:

```
    struct competitors_list_st {
    string competitor_name;
    int competitor_medals;
    };
competitors_list_st competitors_list[2][1000];
```

And I want to create a setter method for this array, one I can call from the constructor.

```
void set_competitors_list(int rows) {         
    
    int rowCounter, colCounter, cols, sum = 0;
    
    for (rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < 2; rowCounter++) { 
        for (colCounter = 0; colCounter < columns; colCounter++) {                
             //???
            cout << "Enter information for sportist:";
            cin >> name >> medals;
            competitors_list[colCounter][rowCounter] = medals, name;
       }
        
    }
    
}
```

For the first loop I am looping 2 times, because I know the columns are 2, but the number of rows is determined by the user. I am getting an error at the cin>> line - no operator matches these operands            operand types are: Coach::competitors_list_st [2][1000] [ std::string ].

I basically want the user to input number of columns, then input two values that need to be stored in the array. Is this the right approach for this? Where is my mistake?

Comment: `competitors_list[colCounter][rowCounter] = competitors_list_st{name, medals};`  *Is this the right approach for this?*  I'd use a `std::vector<std::pair<competitors_list_st, competitors_list_st>>`, and special care for `name` because of spaces, and check input for failure (unless input is guaranteed to be sanitized).

Comment: In addition to what @Eljay has given, it should be competitors_list[rowCounter][colCounter], the array is defined as `array[noOfRows][noOfColumns]`. It seems that you have not passed columns as well.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing up rows and columns. If there are two columns, why `rowCounter < 2`?

Answer (score 0):

I just don't quite understand what purpose this array fulfills if I knew, I could tell you better than I do now.

But you can try this:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct competitors_list_st {
    string competitor_name;
    int competitor_medals;

    //Initializator (competitors_list_st("test", 10))
    void setData (string s, int m)
    {
        competitor_name = s; 
        competitor_medals = m;
    }
};
competitors_list_st competitors_list[2][1000];

void set_competitors_list(int rows) {

    int rowCounter, colCounter, cols, sum = 0;

    for (rowCounter = 0; rowCounter < 2; rowCounter++) {
        for (colCounter = 0; colCounter < rows; colCounter++) {
            //???
            cout << "Enter information for sportist:";
            string name;
            int medals;
            cin >> name >> medals;
            competitors_list[rowCounter][colCounter].setData(name, medals);
        }

    }

}

void main() {

    set_competitors_list(1);

    for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++) 
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 1; col++)
        {
            cout << '\n' << competitors_list[row][col].competitor_name << ' ' << competitors_list[row][col].competitor_medals;
        }
    }

}
```